# ng lint is analyzing node_modules content - tslint.json and *.ts files

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint, codelyzer

I'm developing npm packages. I publish them to internal nexus npm repository. I publish everything (for the time being, just for simplicity). So after installation, `node_modules/my_package` has everything like in development, including `tslint.json` file and `*.ts` files.

Now when I run `ng lint` from application that is using `my_package` it is finding `tslint.json` in `node_modules/my_package` and starts linting from `node_modules/my_package` level. Because `devDependencies` are not installed (one of them is `codelyzer`, I get error:

> Failed to load C:\Dev\angular-2-poc\Angular2-POC\demo-app\node_modules\my_package\ui\tslint.json: Could not find custom rule directory: node_modules/codelyzer

If I remove `tslint.json` from `node_modules\my_package` , it is not throwing this error any more, but it is still linting `node_modules\my_package` . And because linting rules for may be different between `my_package` and application that is using it, I'm getting errors.

Anyway, is this correct behavior of `ng lint` (I'm using `@angular/cli: 1.1.0`), I mean why it goes into `node_modules` at all?

Comment: add `exclude` in your src tslint.json

Comment: For 'could not find custom rule directory' also see: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-tslint/issues/72